# How to print a value by comparing 2 fields inside JSON - RestAssured

Tags: java, json, eclipse, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Consider the following dataset:

```json
[
    {
        "_id": 1234,
        "bagnumber": "A",
        "bagtype": "coin"
    },
    {
        "_id": 2345,
        "bagnumber": "B",
        "bagtype": "cash"
    },
    {
        "_id": 3456,
        "bagnumber": "C",
        "bagtype": "coin"
    },
    {
        "_id": 5678,
        "bagnumber": "D",
        "bagtype": "cash"
    }
]
```

I need to extract and print the bag numbers that have the bag type "cash" exclusively. Thus, the desired output should be:

```
Bag numbers are: B, D
```

I attempted to extract the bag numbers first using a list:

```java
List<String> bagNumbers = response.jsonPath().getList("bagnumber");
```

Subsequently, I tried to retrieve the bag types using the same list and attempted to compare the two lists. However, my attempts were unsuccessful, possibly indicating an overly complicated approach.

Could someone kindly suggest a more efficient solution? Perhaps utilizing the Matchers class or any other suitable approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)

I suggest Gson or Jackson for Json process.

If the input are string, convert it to JsonArray using:

```
JsonArray jsonData = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonArray.class);
```

Create a List containing result:

```
List<String> listBadCashNumber =new ArrayList<>();
```

Start iterating through array:

```
for(int i = 0;i<jsonData.size();i++){
    JsonObject bag = jsonData.get(i).getAsJsonObject();// Because each element off array is a object
    if(bag.get("bagtype").getAsString().equals("cash")){ // Compare the field 'bagtype', you should handle the null if needed
        listBadCashNumber.add(bag.get("bagnumber").getAsString()); // Add to result list
    }
}
System.out.println("Bag numbers are: "+listBadCashNumber);
```

And the result is:

```
Bag numbers are: [B, D]
```

Comment: the input is a get method. Output i get is json array like "[ {}, {}, {} ]", how to convert them to JsonArray object ?, and when i try, the ".fromJson" - it throws error to use "tojson"

Comment: @user2024 What is 'get method' in this context? the valid input of .fromJson is a Reader or a String. You should convert input to String.

Comment: in RestAssured, i used GET Method from a url which returned a response in Json Array format i.e "Response = [ {}, {}, {} ]" (eg Dataset i gave above) - so while getting the response, i should get them as [B,D]

Comment: "Response = [ {}, {}, {} ]" is not Json Format, I think you are mentioning Response = "[ {}, {}, {} ]", so, you must convert it to String by it's method, like .toString(), or .getBody() or .getResponseBody(), .getBody().entity(), ..... then you convert it using Gson.

Comment: i actually did these steps yesterday and able to fetch the Bag numbers success. 
1. Converted the response to string using String stringresponse = response.asString();
2. Then conveted them to a JsonArray using JsonArray jsonData = new Gson().fromJson(stringresponse, JsonArray.class);
then your suggestions - Able to fetch it : ) Thank you !

Comment: @user2024 good to hear it.

Comment: can you make it as solved

Answer (score 0):

You may try JSON library *Josson* and your request can be done by short statement and functions.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "    {" +
    "        \"_id\": 1234," +
    "        \"bagnumber\": \"A\"," +
    "        \"bagtype\": \"coin\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"_id\": 2345," +
    "        \"bagnumber\": \"B\"," +
    "        \"bagtype\": \"cash\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"_id\": 3456," +
    "        \"bagnumber\": \"C\"," +
    "        \"bagtype\": \"coin\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"_id\": 5678," +
    "        \"bagnumber\": \"D\"," +
    "        \"bagtype\": \"cash\"" +
    "    }" +
    "]");
String output = josson.getString("[bagtype='cash']*.bagnumber.join(', ').prepend('Bag numbers are: ')");
System.out.println(output); // "Bag numbers are: B, D"
```